# How to get unique children in a many to many relation?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make a list of the genres which have books. Multiple books can have the same genre, but list should not have duplicates.

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction)')

class Book(models.Model):
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
```

Comment: So you want all `Genre`s that have at least *one* related `Book`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a list of `Genre`s that have *at least* one *related* `Book` with:

```
Genre.objects.filter(book__isnull=False).distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` is necessary here, since otherwise you will obtain the `Genre` in your queryset, once per related `Book`.

Django will construct a query for this that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT genre.*
FROM genre INNER JOIN book_genre ON genre.id = book_genre.genre_id
WHERE book_genre.book_id IS NOT NULL
```